# Angular POST RESTful API to Ejb resulting in 404 not found error

Tags: java, angular, spring, api, ejb

I was having some problem when trying to send RESTful API from Angular to EJB. Here is my component.ts:

```
this.opUserAdminWinService.retrievePegRoleList().subscribe(resf => {
        console.log(resf);
});
```

And my service.ts:

```
serviceAPI = SERVER_API_URL;
mainAPI = '/api/securityactivity/securityactivity';
retrievePegRoleList() {
    const url: string = this.serviceAPI + this.mainAPI + '/RetrievePegRoleList';
    return this.http.post(url, this.httpOptions);
}
```

In my Controller.java:

```
@PostMapping("/RetrievePegRoleList")
public Vector RetrievePegRoleList()
    throws JaMClientRemoteException, JaMException {
    return getSecurityActivity().RetrievePegRoleList();
}
```

In my EjbBean class:

```
public Vector RetrievePegRoleList() throws JaMClientRemoteException, JaMException;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public Vector RetrievePegRoleList() throws JaMClientRemoteException, JaMException
{
    Vector pegRoleList;
    try {
        String dataSource = JaM.getProperties().ORD_DATA_SOURCE;
        RetrievePegRoleListTask retrievePegRoleListTask = new RetrievePegRoleListTask(dataSource);
        retrievePegRoleListTask.execute();
        pegRoleList = retrievePegRoleListTask.getResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new JaMClientRemoteException(this.ERR_EXCEPTION_JAM, e.toString());
    }
    return pegRoleList;
}
```

However, I am getting this error message:

[image]

Any ideas why is it so? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the configuration or code that make the rest service available at the `/api/securityactivity/securityactivity/RetrievePegRoleList` context?

Comment: @SteveC Sorry but what do you mean by available?

Comment: Somewhere you have `/api/securityactivity/securityactivity/` configured in code or configuration files. Please show how you did that on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

try this in angular.

```
export const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
};
```

```
this.http.post(your-url,your-data, httpOptions);
```

I always send post like this in angular.
If it doesn't work. You should examine,is there an interceptor in Server.

Comment: Let's say my data is null whereby I do not need to pass in any parameters since I am just retrieving, I should modify to .post(your-url,null, httpOptions);?

Comment: Yes. Let us have a try.

Comment: oh. you should examine your url. It's easy to  examine your url .First,change server mapping to Get.And then,use browser to visit the url. If server get the request, the url is right